# Find the smallest m for which this is possible

Tags: combinatorics

Problem:
Eight singers participate in an art festival where m songs are performed. Each song is performed by 4 singers, and each pair of singers performs together in the same number of songs. Find the smallest m for which is possible.

My solution :

Let $k$ is the number songs that each pair of singers performs together.

Now if singer A and B sing together one song we count 1

Now each song performs by 4 singers so . There is all $m.C_4^2$.

$$kC_2^8=mC_2^4$$

So the smallest m is 14 and at that time $k=3$

Comment: $m=0$ seems to be a solution.  Depending on the quality of the singers, it might be optimum.

Comment: @Haruboy15: I flagged that comment as "rude or offensive". Ross made a very pertinent observation (garnished with subtle humour, I might add), and you call him stupid. That would be bad enough even if his comment were wrong, but perhaps the fact that he was right might motivate you to be more cautious in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is correct, if hard to follow.  I would say it more like there are $C^4_2=6$ pairs of singers on the stage for each song, which means $6m$ pairs perform in total.  There are $C^8_2=28$ pairs of singers, so we need $6m$ to be a multiple of $28$, which gives $m=14$ as the smallest solution.  This leads to each pair being on the stage $3$ times.

This proves that the number of songs must be a multiple of $14$, but you have not shown that there is a solution with $m=14$.  It might not be possible to arrange the singers properly.  To find a solution we think about the seven songs that singer $1$ sings.  She is paired three times with each other singer, so each other singer gets paired with six others besides $1.$  It is appealing to make each pair appear once together during the seven songs.  Then we can take the opposite group for the other seven songs.  This leads to $$\begin {array}&1234&5678\\1256&3478\\1278&3456\\1357&2468\\1368&2457\\1458&2367\\1467&2358 \end{array}$$ which I believe satisfies the requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much, I´m finding the way to show thay m=14 ia the solution of this problem,and you help me so, thanks you so

Comment: The hardest part is the construction I think.